# Adobe flex maximum size of uploaded file

Tags: php, apache-flex, file, actionscript, upload

Is there a maximum size limit for files being uploaded in Adobe Flex?
I am testing it on localhost and can't upload a file of roughly 300MB.
Even though I receive the complete event, after I upload the file....
I was able to upload a file of roughly 10MB.
I am using PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that PHP is not accepting the file because it is too big. You need to make sure the PHP configuration values [`upload_max_file_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) are bigger than the file you are uploading.